# how do i use pure javascript/(ajax) with a bitbucket access token to get JSON data?

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, bitbucket

I'm not really sure if it will work or not without using a server, but I did get a response.  So it do think it might be possible.  Here is what I've tried so far, the following being the callback site

```
<html><head><script>
window.onload = function(){
    try{
        var url = window.location.href.split("#"); 
var token = url[1];
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        try{
        var myObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        document.body.innerHTML = myObj.name;
            alert("worked");
        }catch(e){alert(e);}
  }else{
        document.body.innerText = this.response;
        alert("didn't exactly work");
    }
};
xmlhttp.open("get", "https://bitbucket.org/!api/2.0/user/"+token, true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer '+token);
xmlhttp.send();
    }catch(e){alert(e);}
}
</script></head><body>
<iframe id="testframe"></iframe>
</body></html>
```

The response is an error message, which says Access Token Has Expired, try refreshing the page.

The end goal is to use the Bitbucket API, using bitbucket sites only and w/o running a server of my own.

Comment: https://moorescode.bitbucket.io/test.html#access_token=7fpWoyz6_xnVmJhea4DcQ2Bg6x7mcVWwfisYUoyNiyMbaKUv5bD6XUBsai8fRQ1qGIIv9dBHBTVqR09s1QwHpPsVrg8bLPW5le4LBS2kyUPwrnlSjYJwHTk%3D&scopes=repository%3Adelete+repository%3Awrite&expires_in=7200&token_type=bearer

Comment: Have you taken a look at the [documentation](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/oauth-on-bitbucket-cloud-238027431.html) for BitBuckets OAuth? Specifically the "Implicit Grant" flow?

Comment: I post the access token to another server (*.000webhost.com) with a wildcard and I had success when trying to read JSON object, but when I post the token to another page on bitbucket, I received the message "This endpoint does not support token-based authentication".